# Find blank cells in column A and count them

Tags: vba, excel

I would like some assistance in creating a macro that reviews column A of sheet 2 and counts the number of blank cells. If that number equals 0, I would like for it to move on to have it to go to another section of the macro (let's call it alpha). If the number is greater than 0, u would like it to go to a separate section (let's call it beta).

I know =COUNTBLANK is a formula, but creating a macro for this would be helpful.

So far I have:

```
Dim rng as Range
Set rng = Sheets ("Xml").Range("A1:A7000")
NumberOfBlankRows = WorkSheetFunction.CountBlank(rng)

If NumberOfBlankRows = 0 Then
    GoTo ----This is the part where I want it to go to Alpha----
Else
    GoTo ----This is the part where I want it to go to Beta----
EndIf
```

Comment: Just use `NumberOfBlankRows = WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(RangeName)` in the macro.

Comment: I just edited the main post to show what I have so far. Thanks!

Comment: You are only interested to check if there's a blank or not in a given range? Is that right? You're not really after the count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you seek how to implement the `goto` mechanism within your subprocedure. The solution is as easy as adding the labeled Alpha and Beta blocks of code after the main body of your sub and taking care of the exit points, like this:

```
 Sub delegate()

            Dim rng as Range
            Set rng = Sheets ("Xml").Range("A1:A7000")
            NumberOfBlankRows = WorkSheetFunction.CountBlank(rng)

            If NumberOfBlankRows = 0 Then
                GoTo Alpha
            Else
                GoTo Beta
            EndIf

            Exit Sub

        Alpha:
            ' Alpha's body goes here
            Exit Sub

        Beta:
            ' Beta's body goes here
            Exit Sub

 End Sub
```

Generally though, `goto` statements are considered *evil* as they obscure the flow of code leading to devious bugs. Additionally this technique bloats unnecessarily the body of the sub. Consider moving the Alpha and Beta to their own subs (or functions if needed).

I am providing a more generic example with my solution that applies to any column, worksheet and workbook. My solution checks a chosen column against its intersection with the usedRange of a selected worksheet. If we check for blanks against all the cells of a column it will always be with some blanks - unless you have such large datasets that use  all the 1,048,576 rows!

```
Sub delegate(A1col As String, Optional shName As String = "", Optional wb As workbook)

    Dim sh As Worksheet, usedColumnCells As Range
    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = activeworkbook

    If shName = "" Then
        Set sh = wb.ActiveSheet
    Else
        On Error GoTo no_such_sheet
        Set sh = wb.Worksheets(shName)
    End If

    Set usedColumnCells = Application.Intersect(sh.usedRange, sh.Range(A1col & ":" & A1col))

    If usedColumnCells Is Nothing Then
        ' Call B as all cells in chosen column are blank
        beta
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' get total blanks in usedColumnCells
    Dim totalColBlanks As Long
    totalColBlanks = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(usedColumnCells)

    ' proceed with the delegation of tasks based on number of totalColBlanks
    If totalColBlanks = 0 Then
        ' call A procedure
        alpha
    ElseIf totalColBlanks > 0 Then
        ' call B procedure
        beta
    End If

    Exit Sub

' error handler
no_such_sheet:
    If Err.Number = 9 Then
        MsgBox ("There is no worksheet named: " & shName)
    End If

End Sub

Sub alpha()
    MsgBox ("I am alpha")
End Sub

Sub beta()
    MsgBox ("I am beta")
End Sub
```

Here is how you can call the above procedure to check against the column A of your example "**xml**" worksheet:

```
call delegate ("a", "xml")
```